# Building Xamarin.iOS Project - Credentials Dialog Keeps Coming

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing an iOS application in Xamarin using visual studio 2017 on MacBookPro. I was able to deploy this application on a test iPhone but whenever I compile the code, it starts asking for credentials and keeps asking for about 12 times. If credentials are entered successfully 12 times in a row then the project builds **successfully**, otherwise the following error appears in visual studio.

"*/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Debug/Phoneword_iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib': bin/iPhone/Debug/Phoneword_iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff (Phoneword_iOS)*"

Below is the message the comes when it starts building.
"**macOS wants to make changes. Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this. macOS wants to use the "System" keychain."**
[Credentials Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfe2V.png)

Comment: If I don't recall it wrong the first time it asks, you are given the option to "Store credentials", in this way it will not ask again.

Comment: I did not see any such option. I have attached the dialog in the link. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Restart the Mac and try to rebuild again, the first time it asks it should have the checkbox.